# jhipster changing users image URL

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to use picture stored on HD as a profile picture of jhipster user, I'm having troubles with the url. I have tried :
`file:///C:/Users/ab/Documents/myApp/uploads/profile_picture.png` - Not worked.

Also tryed to place `profile_picture` in the same folder as the navbar.components.html and changing the url to just: `profile_picture.png`, but the image did not appear on the navbar. However when i am using any img url from any Google image, the profile picture is there.

As I am new with Jhipster I would like to know what am i doing wrong?
Is it possible to use pictures on HD as a jhipster user's profile picture?

Thanks in advance!

All about my project:

`"jhipsterVersion": "4.14.1",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "jwt",
"cacheProvider": "ehcache",
"enableHibernateCache": true,
"websocket": false,
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
"prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
"searchEngine": false,
"messageBroker": false,
"serviceDiscoveryType": false,
"buildTool": "maven",
"enableSocialSignIn": true,
"enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
"jwtSecretKey": "",
"clientFramework": "angularX",
"useSass": false,
"clientPackageManager": "yarn",
"applicationType": "monolith",
"jhiPrefix": "jhi",
"enableTranslation": false`

Comment: Browsers cannot access your local disk.  You need to serve the image from your server.

Comment: thanks, any tips on how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved my problem!
It was really obvious. In your JHipster app directory, there is a file named `target/www/content` which is accessible from the server. So, in your database, in JHI-USERS table, in img_url field write: `content/NAME_OF_PICTURE.png` and it will work.

Comment: You can also test it by writing in URL: http://localhost:8080/content/NAME_OF_IMAGE.png

You must see your image as a result.

Comment: Also in  'target/www/content' you can create new folder (e.g. images), which will also be accessible.